# Does Memgraph support adding relationships to the same node in parallel?

Tags: memgraphdb

I am using Memgraph Platform v2.6.1 and trying to add relationships to the same node in parallel and I get a transaction conflict error. I am wondering whether it is even possible to add relationships to the same node in parallel and if yes, what is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add relationships to the same nodes in parallel. The simultaneous write operations on the same node will always result in a serialization error.